AddColumns with LookUps only brings in Key column from Dataverse
I'm trying to get all necessary data from Dataverse in one query in my Power App
The query is as follows
fxGetMedicalInsuranceRecordFromDataVerse = ShowColumns(
    AddColumns(
        'Medical Insurance Details' As Details,
        Record,
        LookUp(
            ShowColumns(
                AddColumns(
                    'Medical Insurance Records' As Record,
                    PlanCode,
                    Record.'Medical Insurance Record Plan Code',
                    Grade,
                    Record.'Medical Insurance Record Grade'
                ),
                'Medical Insurance Record Declaration Accepted',
                'Medical Insurance Record Employee Number',
                'Medical Insurance Record Enrolment Date',
                'Medical Insurance Record Membership Number',
                'Medical Insurance Record MHD',
                PlanCode,
                Grade
            ),
            wd_name = Details.'Medical Insurance Details Employee Number'
        ),
        Dependants,
        Filter(
            ShowColumns(
                AddColumns(
                    'Medical Insurance Dependants' As Dependants,
                    Relationship,
                    Dependants.'Medical Insurance Dependant Relationship'
                ),
                'Medical Insurance Dependant Date Of Birth',
                'Medical Insurance Dependant Enrolment Date',
                'Medical Insurance Dependant Forename',
                'Medical Insurance Dependant Gender',
                'Medical Insurance Dependant MHD',
                'Medical Insurance Dependant Surname',
                'Medical Insurance Employee Number',
                'Medical Insurance Dependant Full Name',
                Relationship
            ),
            wd_name = Details.'Medical Insurance Details Employee Number'
        )
    ),
    'Medical Insurance Details Address Line 1',
    'Medical Insurance Details Address Line 2',
    'Medical Insurance Details Address Line 3',
    'Medical Insurance Details City',
    'Medical Insurance Details Cost Centre',
    'Medical Insurance Details Date Of Birth',
    'Medical Insurance Details Email',
    'Medical Insurance Details Employee Number',
    'Medical Insurance Details Forename',
    'Medical Insurance Details Full Name',
    'Medical Insurance Details Gender',
    'Medical Insurance Details Home Phone',
    'Medical Insurance Details Id',
    'Medical Insurance Details Mobile Phone',
    'Medical Insurance Details Postcode',
    'Medical Insurance Details Surname',
    'Medical Insurance Details Title',
    'Medical Insurance Details Town',
    Dependants,
    Record
);

I've tried without ShowColumns, I've tried with LookUps for each relationship and only for some with each approach yielding the same results.
I'm using the function as follows:
With(
    {
        currentUserMedicalInsuranceRecord: LookUp(
            fxGetMedicalInsuranceRecordFromDataVerse,
            wd_medicalinsurancedetailsemail = User().Email
        )
    },
    UpdateContext({locCurrentUserMedicalInsuranceRecord: currentUserMedicalInsuranceRecord})
)

What ends up being populated in the context variable is the details populated with all selected columns loaded, the Record then contains it's relationship columns but only has it's Key column loaded Record with no columns populated
The same for the dependants and their relationship Dependants with no columns populated
I've tried without ShowColumns and with, I've tried using LookUps for each relationship and I've tried adding the relationship as a separate column with no luck
